# Calcular y Mostrar equipo ganador y Puntaje Mayor

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un ejercicio donde se debe de calcular el puntaje mayor y el equipo ganador. Esto mostrando en una caja de texto o en un mensaje.

**Pero estoy aplicando la siguiente función y estoy teniendo problemas por que cuando coloco en el primer equipo = rojo su puntaje 4 y en el segundo Equipo = amarillo y su puntaje 10, me está arrojando que el equipo ganador es el rojo.**

Adjunto Script.

```js
function Calculartc() {
  var p = document.querySelectorAll('select[id^="c"]');

  var mayor = 0;
  var ganador = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {

    if (mayor < p[i].value) {
      mayor = p[i].value;
      ganador = p[i].parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("input").value;

    }
  }

  document.getElementById('ganador').value = ganador;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <script src="cal.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>equipo1</p> <input type="text" name="txtequipo1c" placeholder="Equipo1 *" class="form-control" id="equipo1c">
  <p>puntaje1</p>
  <select name="cboscore1c" class="form-control" id="c">

    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>26</option>
    <option>27</option>
    <option>28</option>
    <option>29</option>
    <option>30</option>

  </select>
  <p>equipo2</p><input type="text" name="txtequipo3c" placeholder="Equipo *" class="form-control" id="equipo3c">
  <p>puntaje2</p>
  <select name="cboscore3c" class="form-control" id="c">

    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
    <option>13</option>
    <option>14</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>16</option>
    <option>17</option>
    <option>18</option>
    <option>19</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>21</option>
    <option>22</option>
    <option>23</option>
    <option>24</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>26</option>
    <option>27</option>
    <option>28</option>
    <option>29</option>
    <option>30</option>
  </select>
  <p>equipo ganador</p><input type="text" name="txtequipoganado" id="ganador">
  <input type="button" value="Calcular Score" onclick="Calculartc(); return false">
</body>

</html>
```

Tal vez estoy aplicando mal la función o me está faltando algún dato adicional.
A su vez estoy tratando de mostrar en un mensaje.

**C.Rodriguez**
He probado tu código pero tengo esta observación

[image: error]

**El código lo he modificado de la siguiente manera.**

```
function Calcular() {
  var p = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  var mayor = 0;
  var ganador = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (mayor < p[i].value) {
      mayor = p[i].value;
      ganador = p[i].parentElement.querySelector("input").value;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('verificacion').value = ganador;
}
```

Pero aún presento ese error, tal vez estoy olvidando algo,he borrado el `parenElement` pero he divido cada equipo con su div correspondiente, pero aún sigo presentando esta falla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Los `id` son únicos, no pueden repetirse. Para eso utliza las clases.
- Debes tener cuidado cuando utilizas `parentElement` para obtener el elemento antecesor, ya que podrías seleccionar elementos que no deseas.

---

Tu código en general funciona bien, el detalle es que al tener dos `id` repetidos, solo está siendo seleccionado uno.

Para esto, deberás cambiar tu selector.

```
var p = document.querySelectorAll('select'); // Lo mejor sería colocar una clase y seleccionarla aquí, sin embargo, a modo de ejemplo podría ayudarte.
```

Igualmente, cuando utilizas `parentElement`, estás seleccionando todos los `input` que tengas en tu HTML (ya que si lo ves jerárquicamente `p` es el elemento seleccionado, el antecesor sería el `body` y el antecesor a ese, tu `html`).

Lo que deberás hacer es 'encerrar' la información de cada equipo en un `<div>`.

```
<div>
    <p>equipo 1</p>
    <input....>
    <p>puntaje1</p>
    <select....>
</div>
<div>
    <p>equipo 2</p>
    <input....>
    <p>puntaje2</p>
    <select....>
</div>
```

Además, en tu código Javascript, deberás eliminar una llamada a tu `parentElement`, quedando de esta forma:

```
ganador = p[i].parentElement.querySelector("input").value;
```

De esta manera, `p` sería tu `<select>`, `parentElement` sería tu `<div>` contenedor, y al ejecutar la función `querySelector`, se seleccionará el `<input>` que tengas en ese contenedor.

Te dejo el ejemplo al editar tu código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**NOTA:** 
Como recomendación, deberás buscar la forma de crear el "empate", en caso de que ambos equipos tengan la misma puntuación, por defecto se elegirá el 1.

---

**EDIT**

Tienes toda la razón, mis disculpas por no haber probado todos los casos (solo probé con números mayores al 10 entre los equipos).

El problema que se genera es debido a que el valor obtenido por `p[i].value` es de tipo `string` y no de tipo `number` como debería de esperarse (para realizar la comparación).

Para solucionar esto, debes convertir primero el valor a `number`:

```
if(mayor<Number.parseInt(p[i].value)){
    mayor=Number.parseInt(p[i].value);
    ganador = p[i].parentElement.querySelector("input").value;
}
```

Por si quieres resumirlo:

```
var value = Number.parseInt(p[i].value);
if(mayor<value){
    mayor=value;
    ganador = p[i].parentElement.querySelector("input").value;
}
```

Comment: Analizando tu conocimiento tienes razón, voy a seguir estudiando para mejorar estos detalles, aplicaré tus cambios muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: ¡Genial! Estamos para ayudarnos entre nosotros :-). Recuerda que, luego de hacer las pruebas necesarias, te sirve esta respuesta, márcala como aceptada.

Comment: Hola C.Rodriguez eh probado tu codigo pero hay una observacion te lo voy adjuntar en la pregunta,si al equipo 1 le pones como puntaje = 4 y al equipo 2  = 10 te arroja que el equipo 1 es el mayor ------- caso contrario deberia ser el equipo 2 ahi te va la observacion

Comment: Hola @kenny, gracias por la observación, ya edité la respuesta (está en **EDIT**).

Comment: Perfecto,se tenia que convertir la cadena en numeros,muchas gracias @C.Rodriguez capo.